# Magento 2 Extension manager (PHP Settings Check*)

Tags: magento2, extensions

I'm using ubuntu 18.04 with PHP 7.3.14. I just purchased a module that I'm trying to install. This is the error I'm receving. How am I supposed to know whats wrong? It tells me that I'm missing PHP extension. I have checked the magento 2 documentation and installed the neccesary PHP extensions. I have cleared the cache and restarted the apache2 server. I have checked the php.ini file to make sure that I have enough memory.

- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/php-settings.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42393376/magento-2-installation-error-php-settings-check

[image]

My php.ini file doesn't show all the modules I have installed which witch makes me a bit confused. Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: but you try the command line because it is best way

Comment: Are you already installed the required php extension (*.so) in your OS and in the path where your php extension module is located? if so, just add extension=extension name in your php.ini, like extension=bcmath